# Как делегировать события на созданные элементы?

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Для созданных элементов в js лучше использовать делегирование. Проблема состоит в том, что когда я создаю новые элементы, они не реагируют на старые или реагируют, но происходит не нужная магия.

Я пробовал вешать события в момент создания элемента, но не работает.
Не могу делегировать, потому что еще новичок, но и потому что не пойму как делегировать 6 событий:

- *drag start*
- *drag over*
- *drag leave*
- *drag enter*
- *drop*
- *drag end*

  на новые элементы.

Покажите пожалуйста, что делать в данной ситуации!

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('control__element__content'),
  textfield = document.getElementsByClassName('control__element-textfield'),
  blockName = document.getElementsByClassName('control__element-name');

function handleDragStart(e) {

  e.target.style.opacity = '0.5';
  dragSrcElm = e.target;

  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', e.target.innerHTML);
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

  return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'control__element__content') {
    e.target.classList.add('control__element-over');
  }
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  e.target.classList.remove('control__element-over');
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  if (dragSrcElm !== this) {
    dragSrcElm.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
  }

  return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  e.target.style.opacity = '1';
}

//------события
[].forEach.call(element, function(elm) {
  elm.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
  elm.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
  elm.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
  elm.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
  elm.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
  elm.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
});
//------события

//--------Создание
crt.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let f = document.querySelector('.control__element__content'),
    div = document.createElement('div'),
    label = document.createElement('label'),
    input = document.createElement('input');

  div.className = 'control__element__content';
  div.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
  label.className = 'control__element-name';
  label.textContent = element.length + '. новый!';
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.className = 'control__element-textfield';
  div.appendChild(label);
  div.appendChild(input);

  div.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
  div.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
  div.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
  div.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
  div.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
  div.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);

  f.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', div.outerHTML);
});
//--------Создание

document.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
  const el = e.target;
  if (el.classList.contains('control__element-name')) {
    el.classList.add('control__element-name-disabled');
    el.parentNode.children[1].classList.add('control__element-textfield-active');
    const text = el.parentNode.children[0].textContent;
    el.parentNode.children[1].value = text;
    el.parentNode.dataset.oldval = text;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  const el = e.target;
  if (el.classList.contains('control__element-textfield-active') && e.keyCode === 13) {
    if (el.value) {
      el.parentNode.children[0].textContent = el.value;
      el.parentNode.children[0].classList.remove('control__element-name-disabled');
      el.classList.remove('control__element-textfield-active');
    } else {
      el.parentNode.children[0].textContent = el.parentNode.dataset.oldval;
      el.parentNode.children[0].classList.remove('control__element-name-disabled');
      el.classList.remove('control__element-textfield-active');
      el.value = el.parentNode.children[0].textContent;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.control__element__content {
  background: #d3d5de;
  width: 400px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: Consolas;
  margin: 5px 15px;
  padding: 6px 0 6px 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: move;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.control__element-name-disabled {
  display: none;
}

.control__element-textfield {
  display: none;
}

.control__element-textfield-active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button id="crt">create</button>
<div class="control__element__content" draggable="true">
  <label class="control__element-name">Перетаскиваемый элемент</label>
  <input type="text" class="control__element-textfield">
</div>

<div class="control__element__content" draggable="true">
  <label class="control__element-name">Второй элемент</label>
  <input type="text" class="control__element-textfield">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысле делегирования в том, что вы вешаете обработчик не на каждый элемент, а на родительский

То есть если у вас есть список элементов, то нужно вешать события на контейнер, в котором находятся эти элементы

```
[].forEach.call(element, function(elm) {
  elm.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
  elm.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
  elm.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
  elm.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
  elm.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
  elm.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
});
```

Вы же вешаете обработчики событий на элемент, которые у вас есть в начале. Те, которые будут созданы потом не будут реагировать на эти события.

Простой пример:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.onclick = (e) => {
   const target = e.target; // элемент который вызвал событие
   const btn = target.getAttribute('data-btn');
   
   // можно нажимать только на нечетные кнопки
   if(+btn % 2 !== 0) alert(`click to ${btn} button`);
}

// этот код для примера, что работают динамические добавленные кнопки
// можете его не разбирать
document.getElementById('more').onclick = () => {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.container button');
  const nextBtn = document.createElement('button');
  const nextBtnIndex = buttons.length + 1;
  nextBtn.setAttribute('data-btn', nextBtnIndex);
  nextBtn.innerHTML = `${nextBtnIndex % 2 === 0 ? 'Non-clickable' : 'Clickable'} #${nextBtnIndex}`;
  
  container.appendChild(nextBtn);
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <button data-btn='1'>Clickable #1</button>
  <button data-btn='2'>Non-clickable #2</button>
  <button data-btn='3'>Clickable #3</button>
</div>
<hr>
<button id='more'>More buttons</button>
```

Теперь, даже если мы будем динамические добавлять кнопки, они будут реагировать на событие клика. Почему это работает? Потому что есть такой механизм **всплытия события**. Механизм позволяет событию всплывать на верх по всем родителям элемента, который изначально вызвал событие, как пузырь, событие поднимается на верх и если у текущего элемента есть обработчик нужного события, то он вызывается.

В вашем случае, просто поместите все перетаскиваемые элементы в один контейнер, ( в него же добавляйте новые ), повесьте на этот контейнер обработчики событий `dragstart`, `dragend` и т.д. ( в них проверяйте св-во `target` у объекта события, что бы понять, то ли пытаются перетащить ) и наслайждайтесь `JS`

Comment: _повесьте на этот контейнер обработчики событий_   
т.е. вешаю на контейнер dragstart `section.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {}`. Потом в нём проверяю `if (e.target.classList.contains('нужный_элемент')) {}` и в условии в созданную функцию передаю как параметр `e` `handleDragStrart(e)`. Верно?

Comment: @user301955, да

Comment: не выходит ничего. Не могли бы вы указать на ошибки мне. Вот [код](https://jsfiddle.net/grizz/m50jc6ka/29/)

Comment: @user301955 вы при событии вызываете сразу все обработчики зачем-то, это не правильно же